After registration the following page opens: https://myApp.by/assets/inputmask/jquery.inputmask.min.js
after the user registers and logs in, the following page opens:
https://myApp.by/assets/inputmask/jquery.inputmask.min.js
enter image description here
why when you first log in it goes not to the home page but to
/assets/inputmask/jquery.inputmask.min.js
As I understand it, this page opens only once. I would really like to understand what’s going on so as not to encounter problems in the future.
The last time I checked the registration form was more than two months ago.. so I can’t say at what point the problem arose.
login.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title th:text=#{login.title}></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache"/>
    <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0"/>
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></link>
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></link>
    <link th:href="@{/css/bootstrap.min.css}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></link>
    <link th:href="@{/css/bootstrap-material-design.css}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></link>
    <link th:href="@{/css/ripples.min.css}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></link>
    <link th:href="@{/css/style.css}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></link>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrap">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" th:text=#{title}></a>
                </div>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" th:utext=#{language}><span class="caret"></span>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="?lang=en">EN</a></li>
                            <li><a href="?lang=ru">RU</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>                         
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="container" id="login">
        <div class = "login">
        <div class="well">
            <form th:action="@{/login}" method="post">
            <span class="login-title" th:text="#{login.title}"></span>
            <div class="text-center" th:if="${param.error}">
                <span class="help-block" style="display: block; color: red" th:text="#{error.login}"></span>
            </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="username" name="username" autofocus="autofocus" th:attr="placeholder=#{user.placeholder}"/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input class="form-control" type="password" id="password" name="password" th:attr="placeholder=#{pass.placeholder}"/>
                </div>
                <div class="text-center">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" th:attr="value=#{login.action}"/>
                </div>
                 <span class="login-title" th:text="#{login.reg.question}"/></span>
                 <div class="text-center">
                    <a class="btn btn-primary" th:href="@{/register}" th:text="#{register.title}"></a>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <footer class="navbar navbar-fixed-bottom footer">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="footer-copyright">
                <a href="https://www.myApp.by">myApp.BY</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
    <script th:src="@{/js/jquery.min.js}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/js/bootstrap.min.js}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/js/moment-with-locales.min.js}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/js/material.min.js}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/js/ripples.min.js}"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#locales").change(function () {
            var selectedOption = $('#locales').val();
            if (selectedOption != ''){
                window.location.replace('international?lang=' + selectedOption);
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>

And Controller
@Controller
public class LoginController {
    
    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;

    @RequestMapping("/login")
    public String login() {        
        return "login";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index(Locale locale, Model model, RedirectAttributes attrs) {
        model.addAttribute("locale", locale);
               
        Object principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();

        String username;
        
        if (principal instanceof UserDetails) {
            username = ((UserDetails)principal).getUsername();
            } else {
            username = principal.toString();
        }
        
        User loginedUser = userRepository.findByLogin(username);
        
        System.out.println("User logined" + loginedUser.toString());
        
        if(loginedUser.isBanned()) {
            return "redirect:/welcomeBanned";
        }
        
        if(SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getAuthorities().contains(Role.DEFAULT)) {
            return "redirect:/welcome";
        }

        if(SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getAuthorities().contains(Role.USER)) {
            return "redirect:/index";
        }
        
        if(loginedUser.getRoles().isEmpty()) {
            return "redirect:/welcome";
        }
        
        return null;
    }

registrationConfirm.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/extras/spring-security">
<head>
<title th:text=#{title}></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache"/>
    <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0"/>
    <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, must-revalidate"/>
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></link>
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></link>
    <link th:href="@{/css/bootstrap.min.css}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></link>
    <!-- Bootstrap Material Design -->
    <link th:href="@{/css/bootstrap-material-design.css}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></link>
    <link th:href="@{/css/bootstrap-material-datetimepicker.css}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></link>
    <link th:href="@{/css/bootstrap-combobox.css}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></link>
    <link th:href="@{/css/ripples.min.css}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></link>
    <link th:href="@{/css/style.css}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></link>
    <link th:href="@{/css/my-style-main-layout.css}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></link>
    <link th:href="@{/css/my-style-center-text-layout.css}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></link>
    
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrap">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" th:text=#{title}></a>
                </div>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" th:utext=#{language}>
                        <span class="caret"></span>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="?lang=en">EN</a></li>
                            <li><a href="?lang=ru">RU</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    </div>
    
    <div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                    <fieldset>
                        <table class="table table-hover">
                            <tr>
                                <td width="1%"></td>
                                
                                <td width="10%">
                                   
                                    <div class="form-group padding-sides-none my_style_one myCenterLayout">
                                        <span th:text="#{registrationConfirm.regSuccConfirmed}"></span>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                
                                <td width="1%"></td>
                         
                            </tr>
                            
                            <tr>
                                <td width="1%"></td>
                                
                                <td width="10%">
                                   
                                    <div class="form-group padding-sides-none my_style_one myCenterLayout">
                                        <a class="btn btn-primary" th:href="@{/login}" th:utext="#{registrationConfirm.label.login}">login</a>
                                    </div>
                                    
                                </td>
                                
                                <td width="1%"></td>
                            </tr>

                        </table>
                    </fieldset>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <footer class="navbar navbar-fixed-bottom footer">
        <div class="container">
            <!--Copyright-->
            <div class="footer-copyright">
                <a href="https://www.myApp.by">myApp.BY</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
    <script th:src="@{/js/jquery.min.js}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/js/bootstrap.min.js}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/js/moment-with-locales.min.js}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/js/material.min.js}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/js/ripples.min.js}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/js/bootstrap-combobox.js}"></script>
    <script th:src="@{/js/bootstrap-material-datetimepicker.js}"></script>
    <script th:src="@{assets/inputmask/jquery.inputmask.min.js}"></script>
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.combobox').combobox();
        });
    </script>
    <script th:inline="javascript">
        $(function(){
            $("input:checkbox#all").change(function(){
                var checked = this.checked;
                $("tbody#tbody input:checkbox").each(function(){this.checked = checked;});
            });
    
            $.material.init();
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>


I solved the problem by removing the line from registrationConfirm.html

I really don’t understand why the line from registrationConfirm.html affected login.html

I think the issue may be in your if statements. Try editing your if null statement with a redirect so that it sends them somewhere like the homepage. This should then stop the programme sending the user to a random url if none of the conditions are met.
So instead of
return null;

Have it has (or choose where you want to send them)
return "redirect:/login"; 


oh .. If the problem was so obvious, I would not have asked that question.
«I think .. return null;» - in any case, this does not explain why the page «/assets/inputmask/jquery.inputmask.min.js» opens only the first time after registration.
P. S. the program does not reach the method «@RequestMapping("/")  public String index». And if statements are not checked
